# What is the default magento admin username and password?

Tags: magento-1.8

I installed a fresh magento. What is the default admin user and password so I can login to the backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default username and password should be that which you added in installation process.

For change username and password, You need to change from database.

The default login is : admin The default password is : 123123

Just run at your sql database:

```
SELECT *FROM admin_user;
```

Then, find the username you want to modify in the listing provided - ‘admin’ in this example. Then, to update the password, type:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';
```

‘qX’ would be changed to whatever you want it to be and same goes for ‘password’

Comment: Rohan, he wants it in Magento 1, sorry that your answer works in Magento 2

Comment: I updated my answer. You can remove your downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The default admin user and password should be same which you set at the time of installation. If you have forgotten what you had set up and you have the access to the database, then you can change the password using the simple process.

1. Log in to the database and open admin_user table.
2. Note down the username for which you want to change the password.
3. Now run the following query:

   **UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(MD5('xxxxxxxxNewPassword'), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';**

Where:

- **`xxxxxxxx`** is the salt key, which can be replaced by any string.
- **`NewPassword`** can be replaced by your desired password.
- Replace **`admin`** by the username which you noted in **step #2**.

Now remove the **var/cache** folder and retry to log in to the admin panel with the username (which you noted earlier) and password (which you set in the last step).

Comment: So if I run this as is, my new password will be `NewPassword`?

Comment: yes, @ShubhamA.

Answer (score 1):

The username and password can be found in install.php

```
 *  --admin_username admin --admin_password 123123 \
```

Alternatively you can reset the password using [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)

```
php n98-magerun admin:user:change-password
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing to this awesome tool. This is available for Magento 2 (for myself): https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Answer (score 0):

You can change password form phpmyadmin

open `phpmyadmin -> select your database -> select table "admin_user"`

And edit record
edit record and change user name or password (MD5 select 
)
Now than login